# JSX Style Var: Combining Multiples

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there a way to combine multiple style objects to one component?

```
export default class Footer extends React.Component{
render(){
    var inline = {
        display: "inline-block",
        margin: "3px"
    };
    var right = {
        textAlign: "right"
    }
    var containerStyle = {
        padding: "8px",
        color: "#DDD",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        fontSize: "12pt"
    };

    return(
        <footer style = { containerStyle }>
            <div className="inline" style = {inline}>Managed By <a href="http://www.midnighthtml.com">MidnightHTML</a></div>
            <div className="inline" style = {right}>All Rights Reserved</div>
        </footer>
    );
}
```

}

I would like the second div to use the "right" style as well as the "inline"

*I am not sure I am using the proper names for these items as I am fresh to React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the objects using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
return(
    <footer style = { containerStyle }>
        <div className="inline" style = {inline}>Managed By <a href="http://www.midnighthtml.com">MidnightHTML</a></div>
        <div className="inline" style = {Object.assign({}, right, inline)}>All Rights Reserved</div>
    </footer>
);
```

Or [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (stage 4 proposal - might require a [babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)):

```
return(
    <footer style = { containerStyle }>
        <div className="inline" style = {inline}>Managed By <a href="http://www.midnighthtml.com">MidnightHTML</a></div>
        <div className="inline" style = {{ ...right, ...inline }}>All Rights Reserved</div>
    </footer>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
var inline = {
    display: "inline-block",
    margin: "3px"
};

var right = {
    textAlign: "right"
}
```

...

```js
var combination = { ...inline, ...right };

return(
    <footer style = { containerStyle }>
        <div className="inline" style = {inline}>Managed By <a href="http://www.midnighthtml.com">MidnightHTML</a></div>
        <div className="inline" style = {combination}>All Rights Reserved</div>
    </footer>
);
```